# Adding last page after main pages?

Tags: c#, rdlc

So, I have a report that shows data in a grouped format. All great.
I want to now add 1 extra page to the end of the report which has some data being passed as a parameter (dynamic image in this case).

How can I get the RDLC to add 1 page after all the other data has been rendered just to show this extra bit of information? 
The same question applies to a "Page of contents"/index too so pages at the beginning of the main report.

Comment: have you tried making the extra pages sub reports?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can:

1. add a `Rectangle` after your `Table` and set its `.PageBreakAtStart`
   property
2. use this `Rectangle` as a container for your `Image` control

Comment: This didn't quite work. It still displayed the rectangle/image on all pages. I had to add another group into the tablix and then add the rectangle/image. I don't like that approach however

Comment: very strange: if your Rectangle is outside any container it should be displayed only one time. you can also try adding another row footer and put your Table here instead of using another group.